# Cannot access source document location with the current permissions

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, translate

```
{
  "inputs":[
    {
      "source":{
        "sourceUrl":"<<source>>",
        "storageSource":"AzureBlob"
      },
      "targets":[
        {
          "targetUrl":"<<target>>",
          "language":"fr",
          "storageSource":"AzureBlob"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Whenever I do post request it gives same permission error even if the source path can directly be accessed from the browser.

`https://alsntranslator1.cognitiveservices.azure.com/translator/text/batch/v1.0/batches`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

The error message you are receiving indicates that the API does not have the necessary permissions to access the storage account.

You can get the SAS-token from the storage account level in the portal.

**Portal:**

*Storage account ->sharedaccesssignature-> check the required permissions and copy the SAS token.*

[image]

**Source file:**
[image]

Now I make the post request with the translator endpoint, which successfully translates English to Spanish.

**Code:**

```
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "storageType": "File",
            "source": {
                "sourceUrl": "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/file.txt<Your-sas-token>"
            },
            "targets": [
                {
                    "targetUrl": "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test1/file2.txt<your-sas-token>",
                    "language": "es"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Request:**
[image]

**Destination file:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get started with Document Translation - Azure AI services | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/document-translation/quickstarts/document-translation-rest-api?pivots=programming-language-rest-api#translate-documents-post-request)